# Propability of drawing at least 5 cards of the same suit?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, combinations

From a deck of 52 cards (the standard deck) I get 7 cards and I want to draw at least 5 cards of the same suit. What is the probability of this event?

I tried to solve this by saying that this probability equals to:

$\dfrac{{13\choose5}.{39\choose2}+{13\choose6}.{39\choose1}+{13\choose7}}{{52\choose7}} \approx 0,76\%$

That's because from the 13 cards of the same suit, we choose exactly 5 (and 2 from the rest 39 cards remain) or exactly 6 (and 1 remains) or exactly 7 of the same suit.

After this, I had to find the probability of getting 3 pairs of any number and 1 card from the remaining ones. There may be 2 pairs of the same number, meaning four of a kind plus one pair plus one card.
I think there are: 
$$26*25*24*46=717600$$ ways for that because at first, from the 26 pairs we choose 1 then from the 25 remaining we choose again 1 then from the 24 remaining we choose 1 and from the 46 cards remaining we choose the last card.

So the posibility of this is $\approx 0,5\%$

Both of the probabilities seem to be too small and I am not sure if the way I calculated them is the right one. Can someone tell me where am I mistaken?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first probability looks correct, except that you forgot to multiply it by the number of suits. The second one is wrong $-$ there are more than $26$ pairs. Also, do the three pairs have to be different, or can you have four of a kind plus one pair?

Comment: Thank you for the first one! For the second one, this isn't specified but I think you may have same pairs (four of a kind plus one pair) .

Comment: Well, decide one way or the other, and edit it into your question.

Comment: Ok, done. But I still don't get how we may calculate the second one. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Find the probability that if seven cards are drawn from a standard deck that at least five of them are of the same suit.

You correctly calculated the number of ways of choosing at least five cards from a particular suit.  However, we also have to choose one of the four suits.  Hence, the probability is 
$$\binom{4}{1}\left[\frac{\binom{13}{5}\binom{39}{2} + \binom{13}{6}\binom{39}{1} + \binom{13}{7}\binom{39}{0}}{\binom{52}{7}}\right]$$

> Find the probability that if seven cards are drawn from a standard that three pairs and one other cards are drawn.

There are thirteen ranks from which the three pairs must be drawn.  For each of the $\binom{13}{3}$ selections of the ranks of the pairs, we can choose two of the four cards of that rank in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways.  This leaves us with $10$ ranks from which we can choose the remaining card and four ways of choosing a card from that rank.  Hence, the probability is 
$$\frac{\binom{13}{3}\binom{4}{2}^3\binom{10}{1}\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{52}{7}}$$

**Note:**  I am using the standard interpretation of three pairs, which is that the three pairs are of different ranks.  If you allow four of a kind, you could count the same hand six ways since there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways of selecting two of the pair to constitute a pair.

Comment: Once we have selected three pairs, we have used three of the thirteen ranks, which leaves us with ten ranks from which to choose the remaining card.  We choose one of these ranks, then choose one of the four cards from that rank.  Alternatively, the three ranks from which we draw the three pairs have $3 \cdot 4 = 12$ cards, which leaves $52 - 12 = 40$ ways to select the other card.

Comment: I don't get why you multiply with 10 in the second one. And thanks for the note!

Comment: The ten represents the number of ranks available from which to choose the last card after we have chosen three ranks for the pairs.

Comment: Yes, now it is all clear to me, thank you @N. F. Taussig !

Answer (score 0):

the correct answer to your 2nd question is:

```
[13*C(4,2) + 12* C(4,2) + 11*C(4,2]*40/3!/C(52,7)
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Your answers become much easier to read if you format the mathematics with MathJax; here's an admittedly rather long but very helpful tutorial on how to do that: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference